# To make the header image responsive

Tags: responsive-design

I´m trying to make Header image responsive. But cant get it to work...
Anyone know what´s wrong?

css,

```
#sliderHolder img,
img {
    max-width: 100%; 
    height: auto; 
}


#sliderHolder {
    background: url("images/wrapperBg1.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    height: 375px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 980px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS.

```
#sliderHolder{background-size: contain;}
```

Just add this property in existing CSS of the ID and it should work.